# Shortest path to sum with given operations

Tags: arithmetic

(Apologies since this was likely asked before, but I cannot find it. )

Is there a way to find the shortest path from some value `V` to some destination value `D` using only addition of values from a given set of numbers `S`?

For example, starting value `V = 0`. Destination value `D=5`.
Allowed operation is only addition (`+`) and only values from the following set: `S={4,-3}`

The solution is `0+4+4-3=D` (or any other ordering of these numbers), but nevertheless, requires at least 3 operations.

Another example, starting value V = 0. Destination value D=4.
Allowed operation is only addition (+) and only values from the following set: `S={3,-7}`
`D=0+3+3+3+3+3+3-7-7=4`. It requires at least 8 operations.

Finally, starting value `V = 0`. Destination value `D=2`.
Allowed operation is only addition (`+`) and only values from the following set: `S={3,-6, -9}`
Is impossible to complete.

So the question is: 
**How to find the shortest path to get from starting value V to destination value D, by only adding numbers from set S?**

How is this called? How can this be figured out? 
Many thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? E.g. Can you solve for integers solutions to $ 4 = 3a - 7b$?

Comment: It is impossible because the three numbers $3, -6, -9$ are multiples of $3$ which on addition or subtraction will always give a multiple of $3$.

Comment: @Doubtnut How to find the shortest path to get from starting value V to destination value D, by only adding numbers from set S? (in the case of 3,-6,-9) the shortest path doesn't exist (or equals infinity)

Comment: @CalvinLin, I didn't understand your question

Comment: @Doubtnut I'm not sure what you mean. For instance, how do you find the shortest path from 0 to 391 using -2,5,11? How can you verify it's the shortest path? How can you tell in the general case if you can get to D in a finite number of steps?
(35*11 + 2*5 + 2*-2)

Comment: Ok! So you want a general formula?

Comment: So I guess what you're looking for, is given integers $n$ and $x_0, x_1, \ldots x_n$, you want
$$
a_0 x_1 + a_0 x_1 + \ldots + a_n x_n = n
$$
so that $\sum_j |a_j| $ is minimised? The question goes: if we find a set of factors $a_i$, is there another set that also satisfies the same relation?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to figure out! Thank you for putting it in math speak :)

Comment: @MattiP.  It is restricted to non-negative $a_j$. Note that only addition is allowed. Subtraction seems to appear because the set S contains negative values.